# Setting IBAction on Custom Cell from xib?

Tags: ios, ios6, uitableview

I created a custom cell in a xib (using Storyboards in iOS6 but created separate xib for cell) and now I'm trying to connect my speaker button to an IBAction in my UITableViewController sublcass.

[image]

I registered my cell in my viewDidLoad:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MissedWordTableCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MissedWordCell"];
```

I've tried a couple of different ways to add the target.  For example, in my tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath, I tried to add the target directly.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MissedWordCell";
MissedQuestionEntity *missedQuestion;

// forIndexPath: is iOS6
MissedWordTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
// Add target here?  Didn't work. @selector(playWordAction) or @selector(playWordAction:) 
//    [cell.playAudioBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(playWordAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I also tried to set the File Owner to my Table View Controller in my Custom cell xib, but still didn't work.

Here's my error message:

```
2013-07-30 07:47:15.833 Spanish[69420:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception     
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI doIt]: unrecognized selector sent to instance     
0xec34430'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x231e012 0x172de7e 0x23a94bd 0x230dbbc 0x230d94e 0x1741705 0x6752c0 0x675258 0x736021 0x73657f 0x7356e8     
0x6a4cef 0x6a4f02 0x682d4a 0x674698 0x1c0bdf9 0x1c0bad0 0x2293bf5 0x2293962 0x22c4bb6 0x22c3f44 0x22c3e1b     
0x1c0a7e3 0x1c0a6
```

Comment: You are calling `doIt` method on some place in your code, please check

Comment: Yes, that is the IBAction connection that I made in the custom cell xib to the file owner (my subclass of UITableViewController).

Comment: doIt IBAction with playAudioBtn button? or something else?

Comment: Your `doIt` method is being called on a `NSArray`.  That probably means that your action's target has been deallocated and its memory re-used for an array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In **UITableViewCell** just register the property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *playSoundButton;
```

In your **UITableViewController**:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"YourCustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"YourCustomCell"];
    // ...
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   YourCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YourCustomCell"];

   [[cell playSoundButton] addTarget:self action:@selector(playWordAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //...
}

-(IBAction) playWordAction:(id) sender
{
    // do what you want to
}
```

Comment: This looks like what I described as something that I tried?  How is this different?  My selector wasn't found. I must be missing something else?

Comment: I suppose that you are adding a IBAction on UITableViewCell, but you don´t need to! Just register the property, or... take a look at "-(IBAction) playWordAction:(id) sender"

Comment: Never mind. This does work. I must have had something else wrong before I tried the second method.