# How to utilize actions with two views in custom UITableViewCell XIB?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I currently have a UITableViewCell set up with two views, a bottom and top view. The top view consists of all the default text, and the bottom view will contain two buttons. (One right now for Delete as seen in picture below)
[image]

Right now I have two UIGestureRecognizers set up, one to slide left and the other right on the cell. When they slide left on the cell, the bottom view slides over half way hiding half of the top view, and if you slide back right it hides the bottom view. (as shown above)

Now my question is: How would I go about making it so when a user clicks on Delete it will delete that from the tableview and Parse.com backend?

I have already written the code to delete the specific event once in the detail view controller by doing this (first allocating and initing the detail view and setting object property on table view controller to object property on detail view controller called selectedEvent):

```
PFRelation *relation = [self.currentUser relationforKey:@"watching"];
[relation removeObject:self.selectedEvent];
[self.currentUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (error)
    {
        NSString *errorString = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
        UIAlertView *errorAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:errorString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [errorAlertView show];
    }
    else
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"Removed from Watch List!"];

}];
```

But not understanding how I would do it from the actual Tableview considering Delete button and method will be located on the actual CustomCell XIB file so its not like I'm setting it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath in table view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works similarly to any other element in your view controller. You simply need to create your IBActions in the ViewController where you have your UITableView. After that go to the XIB  and use the Connections inspector to link the event you need (ie.: Touch Up Inside) to your IBAction.

Given that all the buttons in all your rows will be calling the same method, make sure to store the row index in the tag of each of the buttons.
In your cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
cell.yourButton.tag = indexPath.row;
```

So that, on your IBAction method you can gather that rowIndex to know in which cell of the tableView the button was clicked:

```
- (IBAction)onDeleteButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    const int rowIndex = ((UIButton *)sender).tag;
    ...
```

EDIT 2:
You can do the same thing by referring to your method inside of cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onDeleteButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

EDIT 3:
To remove one row from your list by using an animation, you can use

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowIndex inSection:0]]
                                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
```

There are other options to change the row animation as well as ways to delete many items at the same time. All within Apple docs.

Comment: I still don't see how that works considering I would be making the UIButton object in the CustomCell.XIB so that it displays the Delete button on each cell and not the actual Viewcontroller.XIB where the Tableview is. So that would make it so I can't really connect the IBAction to the Button now considering you said IBAction has to be in tableView view controller.. and button his in custom cell.xib

Comment: Sure you can! Just open the XIB and the your tableView VC code, and relate them by dragging Command + click.
You can do the same thing by code. (Check the last edit)

Comment: No I mean I can't relate them considering the UIButton is on my CustomCell.XIB (Custom UITableViewCell) which uses CustomCell.h/.m and The tableview is on my ViewController.XIB which uses ViewController.h/.m - So how am I going to relate the action you're telling me to create in my Viewcontroller's cellForRowAtIndexPath with an outlet located on the CustomCell View Controller

Comment: Check "EDIT 2". You do have access to your cells from your viewController since you are setting your cells in your cellForRowAtIndexPath. Here's another example of the same thing.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946524/setting-ibaction-on-custom-cell-from-xib

Comment: Oh okay! I guess my confusion was the empty circle next to the IBAction on the TableViewController.. didn't see how that would work out if it wasn't connected to anything, but I set a breakpoint and sure enough the function was hit.

Comment: Now it seems [self.tableView reloadData]; doesn't want to work here: but will work when I click out of the view and back in (I have that same line in viewDidLoad which is why) but why would it work in one situation but not the other?

Comment: Also remember that when you link your event with firstResponder, the circle doesn't get filled.
When are you trying to reloadData? and from where? If your source array doesn't change, so won't the tableView.

Comment: Well I call [self.tableView reloadData]; on viewDidLoad which works fine, every time I click out of the view and load it again any that were removed , are gone from UITableView. But the problem is now (keep in mind this is the same ViewController!) when I added [self.tableView reloadData]; to the deleteBtn Action like this:
http://pastebin.com/Pugqut8j

It didn't work... it removes it just fine, and if I reload the ViewController it will disappear, but I want it to disappear once it's removed (in the success part of the block) which is what I thought I was doing...

Comment: To see a difference when doing reloadData, you first need to remove a given item from the NSarray you are using to back your tableView and then do a reloadData.
Also check out those cool animations to give a user a better feedback when making a row disappear from the list. Check EDIT 3.